# Working with variable from SQL DataReader

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have read the int "anzahl" with DataReader. Now I want to work with this number. The problem is: I cannot access the int from outside the while loop. The error shows "use of unassigned local variable". How can i make "anzahl" available? Here is my code:

```
int anzahl;
string uid = uidTextbox.Text;
string query1 = string.Format("SELECT Chip_Anzahl FROM chipTable WHERE Chip_ID = '{0}';",
                              uid);

try
{
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlConnection);
    sqlCmd.CommandText = query1;

    sqlConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dataReader.Read())
    {
        anzahl = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
    }

    dataReader.Close();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception E)
{
    MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
}

int newnumb = anzahl + 5;
MessageBox.Show(newnumb.toString());
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) | [SqlCommand Parameters Add vs. AddWithValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110001/sqlcommand-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue)

Comment: `int anzahl = 0;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Use of unassigned local variable' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343880/how-to-fix-use-of-unassigned-local-variable-in-c-sharp) and [Why did I get the compile error “Use of unassigned local variable”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233000/why-did-i-get-the-compile-error-use-of-unassigned-local-variable)

Comment: Also, seems like this should be an `ExecuteScalar()` situation, rather than `ExecuteReader()`

Answer (score 3):

The specific problem you're running into is C# is not able to determine `anzahl` is [**definitely assigned**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables). That is, there are scenarios where this line never runs:

```
anzahl = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
```

But this line still does:

```
int newnumb = anzahl + 5;
```

If that happens `anzahl` is undefined, which is not permitted.

The naive fix is a simple adjustment to the variable declaration:

```
int anzahl = 0;
```

This will allow the code to compile and run (mostly) as you expect. However, it's probably worth your time to understand those edge cases some more... *especially* the edge cases around **SQL INJECTION** as described in the comments.

A more complete fix might look like this:

```
//put this in a separate file, and move ALL database access into this class
public static class DB
{
    private string ConnectionString {get;} = "connection string here";
   
    public static int GetAnzahlByChipUID(string chipUID)
    {
        string query1 = "SELECT Chip_Anzahl FROM chipTable WHERE Chip_ID = @chipUID;",
                            
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@chipUID", SqlDbtype.VarChar, 64).Value = chipUID;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            return (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}

//Then call it from the existing location like this:
try 
{
    int anzahl = DB.GetAnzahlByChipUID(uidTextbox.Text);
    int newnumb = anzahl + 5;
    MessageBox.Show(newnumb.ToString());
}
catch (Exception E)
{
    MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
}
```

Note the use of `sqlCmd.Parameters` to set the value for `@chipUID`. This does NOT do a simple string substitution. Real injection protection quarantines the parameter data in a completely separate area from the SQL command text, to prevent any possibility of injection.